# "Information content" of entropy in layman terms for non-computer scientists

Tags: definition, information-theory, entropy

"Uncertainty", "unpredictability", "randomness", "information content" have all been used to describe what differential entropy measures. The first two definitions rein in unrequited comparisons with variance and volatility. To me, "randomness" resonates the best, having a stats background, but I struggle to convey the meaning of the last one especially.

If entropy measures information content of a random variable's statistical distribution, how can "information content" be put in layman's terms for a different scientific discipline that doesn't understand bits or any computer science jargon, nor deals with messengers and receivers, given that a low entropy variable is said to be "more informative" than a high entropy variable? maybe what I'm really looking for is a synonym for usage in place of "information"

Comment: I am increasingly of the opinion that it's actually quite misleading to think of entropy in terms of "information content." There's an important sense in which random noise, which has the highest possible entropy, contains no information whatsoever!

Comment: yes, "content" suggests the polar towards the maximum rather than the minimum, counterintuitive to the negative relationship between entropy's magnitude and "informativeness". how can the term be inverted? "information [antonym of content here]". but that would only correct the polar direction, and we're still stuck with explaining what information even means

Comment: How about "allows the greatest variety of expression"?

Comment: Probably dup: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599817/entropy-average-information-vs-uncertainty

Comment: @QiaochuYuan A highly compressed file (say, a .mp4 video) "is" white noise (in the statistical sense of "is"). Same for the digits of $\pi$.

Comment: Looking into this more i felt that information content actually means "unexpected events" which makes more sense. Could someone use this to come full circle with a good laymans description